# find a regular expression where a is never immediately followed by b (Theory of formal languages)

Tags: regex, theory, formal-languages

I need to find a simplified regular expression for the language of all strings
of a's, b's, and c's where a is never immediately followed by b.

I tried something and reached till (a+c)*c(b+c)* + (b+c)*(a+c)*

Is this fine and if so can this be simplified?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about regular expressions used in programming, or regular expressions in theory? The latter belongs in math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: theory. Okay thank you. I have posted it on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematically regular expressions, and has been reposted on math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!a)b
```

This will find you all the `b` instances that are not immediately following `a`

Or a negative lookahead:

```
a(?!b)
```

This will find you all the `a` instances that are not immediately followed by `b`

Here is a regex101 example for the lookbehind:
https://regex101.com/r/RsqXbW/1

Here is a regex101 example for the lookahead:
https://regex101.com/r/qiDIZU/1

Answer (score 0):

You solution contains only strings from the desired language. However, it does not contain all of them. For example **acbac** is not contained. Your basic idea is fine, but you need to be able to iterate the possible factors. In:

```
(b+c)*(a (a)*(c(b+c)*)*)*
```

the first part generates all strings withhout a.

After the first a there come either nothing, another a or c. Another a leaves us with the same three options. c basically starts the game again. This is what the part after the first a formalizes. The many * are needed to possibly generate the empty string in all of the different options.